# WordPress: How to apply display posts in form of jQuery sliders?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Actually I am making a site which contains an image in the center of the page. I have applied jQuery so that the image will change using next and previous arrows. But I want the image to change via the admin panel not from a script, so I decided to put each image in an individual post. But now I'm confused as to how to apply jQuery to these posts. Please advise what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-featured-content-slider/installation/

Comment: Thanks alooottttt..really you are a life saver...But it still not working fine for me. Images are coming vertically in a line and arrows are not working..:s Is this a kind of conflict of jquery?

Comment: Yeah. If you use any jquery inside your template try removing that. This plugin already come up with a jquery script. Thanks

Comment: Okay I will let you know after 3 to 4 hours. Please please do check my reply whenever you get time. thanks alooottt....

Comment: Brother I deleted all the jquery I used but it still not working. Any other solution you have? Please Help me brother...please

Comment: I can't predict the error. But did you check the them header.php file has the wp_head(); function and the footer has wp_footer(); function?